# Id like a gui for the terminal. Is there any out there?

Tags: command-line, gui

Is there a GUI terminal that provides clickable buttons for commands, such as `apt-get update` or `apt-get autoremove` or `apt-get upgrade`, instead of typing all the time?

Comment: Please edit your answer to clarify it. Gnome-terminal (Ubuntu's terminal) is a GUI program itself. If you want a front-end for APT specify it, but do not say "GUI terminal".

Comment: did I understand the q? :-D If not pm me.

Comment: `aptitude` is my choice when it comes to updating: `sudo apt-get install aptitude` It's a GUI within the console with simple key commands,  but also works with the mouse. U updates (apt-get update), SHIFT & + to add/install (Can be used on entire sections). Then G twice to 'Go' (once to see changes, again to do everything). Doesn't get much easier, I think.

Comment: Would you be happy with a terminal that lets you create your own buttons at the top that paste a command that you choose?

Comment: @DamianYerrick That sounds interesting. Whats it called?

Answer (score 3):

Well you mentioned `apt-get` commands, so You could just use Ubuntu `update-manager` (that's more or less gui for apt-get) and I'm pretty sure there are others like `synaptic` for example.

On the other hand, there is no such thing that You are describing for ALL commands acessible from terminal (imagine, my `ls /usr/bin | wc` has 2186 entries, and that's not all that's possible. And what about all arguments You often need to pass to some program? Like `ls -l ~/Music` or chaining commands with pipes?

Comment: For update manager i noticed that when i would run that i could go to the terminal and do apt-get update and autoremove and there would still be updates and i would run apt-get upgrade to do the rest of the updates. But if i just used the terminal in the first place it would get them all. So that was why i asked about this.  A gui for the most common apt-get. I understand different arguments and what not would need more input. If someone made this they could account for such things like when you click a button for a command it could ask you for more input or give options for it.

Comment: If there is nothing out there then someone needs to get on it.

Comment: apt-get update as You may read in for example `man apt-get` downloads list of new packages. `update-manager` does this on it's own.  "Install updates" button installs, well, all selected packages. So if You have all selected there shouldn't be any more packages to install. 
Anyway - if You don't like update-manager feel free to use `aptitude`, `synaptic` or any other. Or even write Your own shell script to automate those actions.

Comment: What could i use to write it myself? Conky? I use kubuntu more then anything else. Think i could create widgets to do this?   Im not all that hard up for something ya know Just bored and thought there may be something. Creating my own way of doin this would be fun.

Comment: not sure about Conky, I haven't been using it for ages.  You can write it in multiple ways - Java, Qt app. Or even shell script and add for example desktop launcher running it via double click...

Answer (score 2):

No there is not one of such tools. Different graphical tools will perform specific command line instructions. Like "software updater" handles apt-get instructions you also have ...

"Task manager" that handles processes (command "ps"). You can view process, changes niceness, kill a process etc.

"Nautilus" that handles file manager commands. Like "ls", "cd", create/delete files or directories ("touch", "mkdir', "rm").

There is a graphical tool for editing Grub, for mounting, for burning DVDs (where command line is a simple "dd" command).

The 1st 2 will probably cover most of the commands you will need to type.

Gnome terminal (or similar) is a lot more handy to have for any command with any of its options. Auto-complete, help and manual pages are there to make life a bit more easier. The command line is something that needs a bit of experience.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sence. A terminal is something where you type into and not where you click on something.
There are millions commands it wouldn't even possible to make it graphical. But the more general things can be managed through Ubuntu's settings witch are graphical.

*If you just need it for managing packages there is `synaptic` or you could also use the `Ubuntu software center` which is preinstalled.*